# Why not let consumers pull messages from followers?

Tags: apache-kafka

It seems Kafka only allows consumers to pull messages from the `leader` broker (the broker on which the leader partition running). The `followers` only sync with the `leader`, and consumers CANNOT read messages from the `followers`.

**Why NOT let consumers also pull messages from `followers`?**

I think if the consumer can read messages from `followers`, we can have load balancing for reading from all broker servers, and the performance of the whole system should be better. Say, the `leader` is too busy, and the bandwidth of the `leader` becomes a bottleneck. If we can pull messages from the `followers`, the performance should be better.

Answer (score 8):

There is no leader broker in Kafka only leader partitions. A topic is made up of 1 or more partitions. A Kafka broker has multiple partitions, some of which are leaders and some of which are replicas from partitions on the other Kafka brokers in the cluster. This way each broker has some active partitions and so one busy partition on one broker does not make as big of an negative impact on the performance of the other partitions on the remaining brokers.

Comment: +1. You answer makes sense, if there're lots of partitions distributed on lots of brokers. However, if the partition number is small, partitions can NOT distributed on many brokers. B.T.W. When I say leader broker, I mean the broker that the leader partition running on.

Answer (score 4):

@for_stack After playing with kafka cluster to improve performance, I came to the exact same requirement. Looks like kafka improvement proposal [KIP-392](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-392%3A+Allow+consumers+to+fetch+from+closest+replica) would handle this.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: Available from Kafka 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

@for_stack In my opinion, It could be like this because, the producer writes only to the partition leader and just in case in the meantime the replicas are lost before the message is committed. Then in this case it clearly means that the consumer which was reading from the replicas lost the message, which now it has to read from partition leader.

In such a case, it becomes mandatory:-

1). For consumer to know that the replica is out of sync. This could be added functionality on the consumer.

2). Reading from partition leader is straight forward, as partition leader is also in-sync replica in itself and it also acts as the best source of truth.